# In what Layer should be the DomainEventHandler?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, domain-events

I want to use the Domain Events pattern presented by [Udi Dhahan](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)
My application have the fallowing layers:

UI -> Distrebuted Services -> Application Services -> Domain -> Data Layer.

The Domain Layer is responsible for raising Domain Events. In What layer should be the Domain Event Handler that responsible of handling the event?

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere you need it. DomainEvents are also used for communication between bounded contexts, one aggregate root raises an event, other might be interested in the event. So it depends, there are no rules here.